# Are there any female prophets in Quran?

Tags: women, prophets

Are there any female prophets in Quran? If yes, could you give me the link to that passage so I can look at it myself.

Comment: Related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30624/why-were-there-no-female-prophets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Names of the 25 Prophets Mentioned in Al-Quran are as follows:

- Adam(A.W)
- Idris(A.W) (Enoch)
- Nuh(A.W) (Noah)
- Hud(A.W) (Heber)
- Salih(A.W) (Methusaleh)
- Lut(A.W) (Lot)
- Ibrahim(A.W) (Abraham)
- Ismail(A.W) (Ishmael)
- Ishaq(A.W) (Isaac)
- Yaqub(A.W) (Jacob)
- Yusuf(A.W) (Joseph)
- Shu’aib(A.W) (Jethro)
- Ayyub(A.W) (Job)
- Dhulkifl(A.W) (Ezekiel)
- Musa(A.W) (Moses)
- Harun(A.W) (Aaron)
- Dawud(A.W) (David)
- Sulayman(A.W) (Solomon)
- Ilias(A.W) (Elias)
- Alyasa(A.W) (Elisha)
- Yunus(A.W) (Jonah)
- Zakariya(A.W) (Zachariah)
- Yahya(A.W) (John the Baptist)
- Isa(A.W) (Jesus)
- Muhammad(Sallallahu Alihi wassallam)

All of the above are male. **There is no female prophets mentioned in Al-Quran.**

Answer (score 3):

No, there are not; most if not all of the named prophets (Muhammad notwithstanding) in the Qur'an are associated with Biblical persons who are well-known to be male.  Even of those whose biblical counterpart is debated, I know of no dispute over their gender.