# Can Maryam be considered a prophet even though she's a female? Why or why not?

Tags: women, prophets, surat-maryam, maryam

Can Maryam be considered a prophet even though she's a female?

She seems to have had angelic meetings/messages and held in such high esteem by both Allah and followers.

I'm new to understanding Islam, so by what basis is one considered a prophet?

Comment: I assume that your question is covered in my answer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30624/why-were-there-no-female-prophets let me know if not or edit your post!

Answer (score 6):

> Can Maryam be considered a prophet even though she's a female? Why or
>   why not?

In the Quran we find that Allah sent revelations only to men:

> **And We sent not before you, [O Muhammad], except men to whom We
>   revealed [the message],** so ask the people of the message if you do not
>   know. [Quran 21:7]

This clearly indicates that one of the prerequisites of prophets is that they must be men. Since Maryam was a woman, she cannot be considered a prophet.

> I'm new to understanding Islam, so by what basis is one considered a
>   prophet?

The men, among the believers who were inspired by Allah to spread the message of Islam to their people, are considered prophets (peace be upon them all).

Comment: You may want to include the stance of Maryam as one of the four women who completed iman, and that revelations occurred to other than prophets ad in the mother of Mussa.

Answer (score 0):

Can Mary be considered a prophet despite being a woman? Why and why not?
They were not prophets, but they held such a high position that the Holy Qur'an states in verse 42 of Surah Al-Imran:O Mary, God has chosen you, purified you, and chosen you above the women of the worlds.And remember when the angels said: O Mary! God has chosen you and purified you, and has made you superior to all the women of the world.

Ref.: https://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=78685&consultationid=727011