# Did revelations occur to people other than prophets as in the mother of Prophet Moses? If yes, why are they not considered as Prophets?

Tags: prophets, prophet-musa

While going through the below question:

[Can Maryam be considered a prophet even though she's a female? Why or why not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35768/can-maryam-be-considered-a-prophet-even-though-shes-a-female-why-or-why-not)

I came across this comment:

> You may want to include the stance of Maryam as one of the four women
> who completed iman, and **that revelations occurred to other than
> prophets ad in the mother of Mussa.**

***Can someone elaborate on it to help us understand it better.***

Comment: This is answered in https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30624/

Comment: @UmH Thanks but my question is not limited to just females. To rephrase, did "humans" other than the 124000 alluded to in the Hadiths ever receive a revelation from God? If yes, why are they not considered as Prophets?

Comment: The answer touches upon it. There are incidences of non-prophets such as the sahaba seeing and hearing the messages delivered by angels.

Comment: @UmH I remember a similar incident in the Hadith of Angel Gabriel when he came to explain Islam in a white dress to the Prophet in the presence of the Sahaba. But again this revelation was directed at the Prophet and not revealed directly to any of the Sahaba/Non-Prophet which is the intent of me asking the question. Apologies  if I am being unclear in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes وحي has been sent to other than the prophets.

For example you may find in the Quran of it being sent to the disciples ([5:111](http://quran.com/5/111)), to the bees ([16:68](https://quran.com/16/68)), to the earth ([99:5](https://quran.com/99/5)), to the mother of Moses ([28:7](https://quran.com/28/7), [20:38](https://quran.com/20/38)) etc.

Similarly the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/55/15) that mentions an incident among the Children of Israel when an angel was sent to test them, and the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/11) that mentions that the companion Imran bin Hussain was greeted by angels. The [report](https://archive.org/stream/AlSiraAlNabawiyya/Al-Sira%20al-Nabawiyya%20Vol%203#page/n165/mode/2up) that Hudayfa saw and received a message from the army of angels after the battle of Ahzab etc.

It is known that these people were not prophets.

This 'revelation' is different from the revelation that happens to a prophet via Gabriel. It may for example have been in a dream. Or in the form of إلهام which is sent to the heart of a person. Or by an angel sent in the form of a human.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do we know why the people who receive Ilham & True Dreams are not also considered as Prophets?

Answer (score 0):

Revelation is of two kinds; Scientific revelation and practical revelation. The first oath is for the prophets and saints that you hear the news of the unseen, the rules and the law, but the practical revelation is what God inspires in the hearts of the believers, the righteous, the saints to make the right decision, this is public revelation. The practical revelation is like the one he sent to the heart of Moses' mother. So those who have come, God makes good decisions in their hearts, so they should be thankful for the good decisions they make and thank God and know that the right decision is from God.

Ref: https://www.khabaronline.ir/news/415108