# Four prophets among women

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

According to Imam al-Qurtubi, when he was commenting on [surah Yusuf verse 109](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura12-aya109.html):

> هذا رد على القائلين : لولا أنزل عليه ملك أي أرسلنا رجالا ليس فيهم امرأة ولا جني ولا ملك ; وهذا يرد ما يروى عن النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم - أنه قال : **إن في النساء أربع نبيات حواء وآسية وأم موسى ومريم**
>
> “This is the critique of those who are of the opinion ‘And they said: Why are the angels not sent to them?’ (Surah al-An’am:8) which means the ones sent to us are from among the men, not from among the women, jinn or angels. This contradicts with a **narration from the Prophet PBUH**, where he said: “**Indeed from among the women are four prophets which are Eve, Asiah the mother of Moses and Mary**.” (See al-Jami’ li Ahkam al-Qur’an, 9/179; bold emphasis mine)

Can someone determine the source i.e. Hadith book and authentication of this Hadith?

Comment: I guess this is wrongly translated. [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30624/13438) seems relevant.

Comment: Does the Hadith even exist. All the well known authentic ones mention these four great women but neither even give a hint that they refer to prophecy. The best explanation is that these women are great bcuz of their piety and virtue.

Comment: Al-qurtubi seem to affirm the belief that they were prophets bcuz of the supposed Hadith above. I just want to know if it's authentic or can be found in any reliable books of Hadith

Comment: Well as said the hadith seems to exist, but the wording is rather wrongly translated or quoted to fit even more the view held by al-Qurtobi.

Comment: The footnote on [this](https://archive.org/stream/waq73651/11_73661#page/n468/mode/2up) copy states لم نقف عليه I suppose that suggests that it is rather obscure and not found in known present collections.

Answer (score 1):

This is among the mu'allaq hadith quoted by imam Qurtubi. There is no such authentic narration mentioned in the hadith books. Allah clearly says in the Qur'an that He has only sent men as prophets and not women and Prophet of Allah would never contradict what Allah has said. The hadith you had quoted as no basis and is a spurious fabricated text in the name of the prophet ($).